# Are bitcoin commands resistant to race conditions and thread-safe?

Tags: json-rpc

Is concurrency a problem for commands like `sendfrom`,`move`,`sendmany` etc.? I suppose everything is fine after skimming source code, but I want to be sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All these transactions do is create a new transaction (or move entry) in the wallet. Balances are always calculated on the fly (though partially cached) from the transaction list.

Comment: You mean cached, not cashed ?