# Is calling the bitcoind RPC multi-thread safe?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

My application uses bitcoind RPC with a Python wrapper. I want to write one thread that periodically watches a number of addresses by calling "listtransactions". Other threads might need to call other API commands in the meantime.

Is it safe to use bitcoind in such a multi-thread setup? (maybe I will use multi-processing in the end because of Pythons global interpreter lock).

When I searched for an answer I found:

[Are bitcoin commands resistant to race conditions and thread-safe?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12590/are-bitcoin-commands-resistant-to-race-conditions-and-thread-safe)

But I am not sure if this answer applies to my problem (and I am also not sure whether Pieter's "yes" is a reply to the first or the second question).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done safely but it can also be done unsafely. If each thread uses its own connection, then it is safe. If the threads "fight" over the connections, then it won't work.

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful. I will use then

conn = bitcoinrpc.connect_to_local()

in each thread, to ensure each thread uses its own connection.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than polling for transactions, you can use `pynode` or `bitcoin-sniffer` to connect to the node directly and parse transactions as they happen. If the addresses are in your wallet, you can call bitcoind with the `walletnotify` option set, which will execute your command with the details of the new transaction.

Comment: Very useful links. Seems to be a lot easier to use than polling. Many thanks!